# Python -- Do things to current element and next element in list?

Tags: python, list

I want to preform a function, let's say print, on the current and next element in the list. How do you do this without getting an error when you get to the last element in the list?

```
some_list = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

desired output:

```
curr_item: "one"
next_item: "two"

curr_item: "two"
next_item: "three"

curr_item: "three"
next_item: "end"
```

What I have tried:

```
index = 0
for item in list_name[:-1]:
    print item, list_name[index+1]
    index = index+1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can zip the list:

```
some_list = ["one", "two", "three"]

for cur, nxt in zip (some_list, some_list [1:] ):
    print (cur, nxt)
```

Or if you want the `end` value:

```
for cur, nxt in zip (some_list, some_list [1:] + ['end'] ):
    print (cur, nxt)
```

Comment: I feel like every other answer I see from you I comment this, but: zip is magic.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) for this:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> some_list = ["one", "two", "three"]
>>> for x, y in izip_longest(some_list, some_list[1:], fillvalue='end'):
    print 'cur_item', x
    print 'next_item', y


cur_item one
next_item two
cur_item two
next_item three
cur_item three
next_item end
```

Answer (score 2):

We can iterate till second last element using list index. List index could be calculated using len and range function as follows:

```
for i in range(len(some_list)-1):
   print some_list[i], some_list[i+1]
```

Output:

```
one two
two three
```

Comment: I can then add some_list[-1] to take care of my last element. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pairwise recipe from `itertools`, something like:

```
from itertools import izip_longest, tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    fst, snd = tee(iterable)
    next(snd, None)
    return izip_longest(fst, snd, fillvalue='end')

for fst, snd in pairwise(['one', 'two', 'three']):
    print fst, snd

#one two
#two three
#three end
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
some_list = ["one", "two", "three"]

for f, r in enumerate(some_list):
try:
    print('curr_item : ',some_list[f])
    print('next_item : ',some_list[f+1])
    print()

except IndexError :
    pass
```

Output:

```
curr_item :  one
next_item :  two

curr_item :  two
next_item :  three

curr_item :  three
```

Answer (score 1):

One line solution

```
[(cur, nxt) for cur, nxt in zip(some_list, some_list[1:])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    print("curr_item: " + some_list[i])
    if i < len(some_list)-1:
        print("next_item: " + some_list[i+1])
    else:
        print('next_item: "end"')
```

Answer (score 0):

use a linked list to evaluate the list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, dataval=None):
       self.dataval = dataval
       self.nextval = None
       self.previousval=None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
       self.headval = None

    def listprint(self):
       node = self.headval
       while node is not None:
           if node.previousval!=None:
                print("Previous Node",node.previousval.dataval)
           else:
                print("Previous Node is None")
           print("CurrentNode", node.dataval)
           print("\n")
           node = node.nextval        
    
list1 = LinkedList()
some_list = ["one", "two", "three"]
for item in some_list:
    if list1.headval==None:
        currentNode=Node(item)
        list1.headval = currentNode
        currentNode.previousval=None
        previousNode=currentNode
    else:
        currentNode=Node(item)
        currentNode.previousval=previousNode
        previousNode.nextval=currentNode
        previousNode=currentNode
    
list1.listprint()
```

output:

```
Previous Node is None
CurrentNode one

Previous Node one
CurrentNode two

Previous Node two
CurrentNode three
```