# Join items in list that occur before and after keyword python

Tags: python, list

I'm using a name entity recognition model to find names in a text string. For hyphenated names like Jane Miller-Smith, the NER model returns the names seperately like this:

```
names = ['Jane','Miller','-','Smith']
```

What's a simple way to join the items before and after the '-' to one string in this list? So that I have a list of first and last name like `name = ['Jane', 'Miller-Smith']`?

I've so far tried to loop through the list of names based on solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768060/python-do-things-to-current-element-and-next-element-in-list) for different hyphenated name versions:

```
name1 = ['Jane', 'Miller', '-','Smith']
name = ['Jane', '-', 'Marie','Miller', '-','Smith']

new_name = []

for cur, nxt in zip (name, name [1:]):
    print(cur,nxt)
    if cur == '-':
        hyph = cur+nxt
        new_name.append(hyph)
        print("hyph: ", hyph)
    else:
        new_name.append(cur)
        print("cur: ", cur)
print(new_name)
```

But I can't wrap my head around how to combine only the string before and after the hypen and also keep other non-hyphenated strings in the list in order (so that not the last name is suddenly first).

Comment: I don't understand, do you have **one** or **two** lists as input?

Comment: I have one list as input, called names, the examples after that are just different name combinations I tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scan from right to left, replacing the three-element slices whenever a hyphen is found:

```
>>> names = ['Jane', '-', 'Marie','Miller', '-','Smith']
>>> for i in reversed(range(len(names))):
        if names[i] == '-':
            names[i-1: i+2] = [f'{names[i-1]}-{names[i+1]}']

>>> names
['Jane-Marie', 'Miller-Smith']
```

An alternative is to loop left-to-right and build a new result list:

```
>>> names = ['Jane', '-', 'Marie', 'Miller', '-','Smith']
>>> result = []
>>> it = iter(names)
>>> for tok in it:
        if tok == '-':
            tok = result.pop() + '-' + next(it)
        result.append(tok)

>>> result
['Jane-Marie', 'Miller-Smith']
```

Comment: nice in place solution :)

Comment: Hey, just fyi about your alternative, here `tok = result.pop() + '-' + next(it)` you pop from an empty list which results in an error if I understand it correctly

Answer (score 4):

Here the trick would be to join the list with a field delimiter you won't find in your list (e.g., |).

Then, you replace the pattern `|-|` with `-` and you split back using your field delimiter.

```
names = ['Jane', '-', 'Marie','Miller', '-','Smith']

print('|'.join(names).replace('|-|', '-').split('|'))
```

Output:

```
['Jane-Marie', 'Miller-Smith']
```

Comment: The assumption is that `|` is not being used in the text

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I added comments about that. I think there will be at least one char that won't be found in the list. So one delimiter or another.

Answer (score 2):

Using an iterator and [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import chain, pairwise
# for python <3.10, check the pairwise recipe:
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise
# or iterator = zip(names, names[1:]+[''])

names = ['Jane', '-', 'Marie', 'John', 'Miller', '-','Smith']

out = []
iterator = pairwise(chain(names, ['']))
for (a, b) in iterator:
    if b == '-':
        out.append(a+next(iterator)[0]+next(iterator)[0])
    else:
        out.append(a)
        
out
```

compact version:

```
iterator = pairwise(chain(names, ['']))

out = [a+next(iterator)[0]+next(iterator)[0] if b == '-' else a
       for (a, b) in iterator]
```

output: `['Jane-Marie', 'John', 'Miller-Smith']`

Comment: Nice use of itertools.  Interestingly, I don't think a triplewise() would work here even though the hyphenates come arrive as three chunks.

Comment: Fails for example `['Frederick', 'Vane', '-', 'Tempest', '-', 'Stewart']`.

Comment: @Kelly this is not a valid input. The input comes from a library that splits hyphenated names, I guess your example could not be generated (for double names).

Comment: @mozway Why not? The real name is "Frederick Vane-Tempest-Stewart". What does the library produce for that?

Comment: This didn't seem to be possible given OP's original logic, they might clarify if needed. But from a generalization perspective this is correct, I based this answer on pairs of names.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a stack, and keep check the `-` symbol, if found then you need to join the previous word and next word into one

```
name = ['Jane', '-', 'Marie','Miller', '-','Smith']

result = []
for word in name:
    if result and result[-1] !='-':
        result.append(word)
    else:
        symbol = ''
        if result:
            symbol = result.pop()
        word2 = ''
        if result:
            word2 = result.pop()
        new_word = ''.join([word2, symbol, word])
        result.append(new_word)
print(result)
```

output

```
['Jane-Marie', 'Miller-Smith']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def solution(the_list: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    while '-' in the_list:
        hyphen_index = the_list.index('-')
        text_before_hyphen = the_list[hyphen_index - 1]
        text_after_hyphen = the_list[hyphen_index + 1]
        the_list.remove(text_before_hyphen)
        the_list.remove('-')
        the_list.remove(text_after_hyphen)
        x = text_before_hyphen + '-' + text_after_hyphen
        the_list.insert(hyphen_index - 1, x)
    return the_list


print(solution(['Jane', 'Miller', '-', 'Smith']))
print(solution(['Jane', '-', 'Marie', 'Miller', '-', 'Smith']))
```

The output will be like this.

```
python3 main.py 
['Jane', 'Miller-Smith']
['Jane-Marie', 'Miller-Smith']
```

Comment: it works, but it's really not efficient when the list grows in size. Try with `names = ['Jane', '-', 'Marie']*10000`, it takes a few seconds where a linear solution would need milliseconds.

Comment: @mozway It also turns `['Mary', 'Jane', 'Miller', '-', 'Mary']` into `['Jane', 'Mary', 'Miller-Mary']`, so I wouldn't say it works.

Comment: @Kelly I didn't test that far (I should have said "*it might work*"), the `index`/`remove` was enough to me to consider it a solution to avoid

Comment: @mozway Yeah, certainly also slow. [Bit faster working version](https://tio.run/##hY5NCoMwEIX3OcXsktRaKm5KwQsUPIG4EJziQJqEGGk9fWpiFQqFvs38vO8xY2c/GF1erAuhxzuMRk2ejBa6e@AorwwWPQdSCDznQBqSse6jCKp1dSLd40sslNzNZDSUFy1kG2aNFSQh@xpTwqGf3OcAY8w60l7sDzW87tzMj8BvncZYa1IKXezyNEa7lfJHcktsHCFvD2VE/0HFeZEM4Q0).